# How to maintain global static variable values after destroy app while using service in background

Tags: android

I'm working on a service in my app. I'm using some global variables values while running service in background when app destroy manually. But when i'm closing app, all variables become destroy.
How can I use these variables while app destroyed.
Any advise is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Encapsulate variables in a singleton-class and have reference to its intance in your service?

Answer (score 1):

When the App close your variables die, Use SharedPreferences if you want save and read smallthings!

for read:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
int showed = sharedPref.getInt("var", 0);
```

for write:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPre2f = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPre2f.edit();
editor.putInt("var", 0);
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Shared preferences. They are accessible across your application any time anywhere

First save the values  before destroying the app.

```
    SharedPreferences prefs= context.getSharedPreferences("MyValues", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor saveValue = prefs.edit();
    saveValue.putString("Key", "Value");
    saveValue.commit();
```

Now you can get those values from any where.

```
    SharedPreferences prefs= context.getSharedPreferences("MyValues", 0);
    prefs.getString("key", "defaultValue");
```

Comment: I'm using a separate class for SharedPreferences which needs application context to call any method of this class. How can we get context in service class to get values from SharedPreferences class?